# Relação HasManyThrough retorna vazio Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de venda e nessa tela é possível selecionar vários produtos que pertencem a tabela `produtos`, a estrutura das tabelas é a seguinte:

```
vendas:
- id

produtos:
- id

vendas_produtos:
 - id
 - venda_id
 - produto_id
```

O que gostaria de fazer é puxar todos os produtos de determinada venda que estão na tabela `vendas_produtos`, sei que a relação é do tipo HasManyThrough mas quando faç a relação no model o retorno é vazio

```
App\Venda.php

<?php

namespace App\Pdv;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Venda extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'vendas';

    function vendedor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendedor', 'vendedor_id');
    }

    function produtos() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Produto', 'App\Pdv\VendaProduto', 'produto_id', 'id');
    }

    function scopeInfo($query){
        return $this->with(['vendedor', 'produtos']);
    }

}
```

Eu precisaria definir algum método também no Model do `vendas_produtos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do pressuposto que vendas_produtos é uma pivot

Pode usar um relacionamento do tipo ManyToMany ou seja uma "venda muitos produtos um produto muitas vendas"

Documentação  em 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Exemplo

```
function produtos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto', 'vendas_produtos', 'venda_id', 'produto_id') ;
    }
```

Comment: Agora só não entendi porque o hasmanythrough não funcionou, ou eu estou confundindo as lógicas rs

Comment: O hasmanythrough obriga a que exista  um  modelo intermédio, mas no seus caso talvez não se justique.

Answer (score 2):

Se você colocar em sua entity de venda_protudos e ao chamar passar o id da venda

```
public function produtos($id) {
        return $this->hasMany(Produtos::class, 'id', 'produto_id')->where([
            'venda_id' => $id,
        ])->get();
    }
```

Para chamar:

```
$produtos = $objetoVendaProduto->produtos($idVenda)
```